# is it a good practice in python? function shortcuts?

Tags: python, function

is it a good practice that i usually (tend to) do in python?
making shortcut of functions for example:

```
p = print
```

and the i use:

```
p('hello world')
```

or
`p(2**5)`

does it affect on performance? What is your suggestion, is it OK?

Comment: 1) `print` is not a constructor (so what's with the title?); and 2) constructors generally should not have side-effects

Comment: I think this makes code not more readable by others

Comment: I've edited my question! thanks

Comment: Looks like a monkey patch question. Very subjective really. Monkey patching not advised if you can avoid it

Answer (score 4):

A good practice in Python is: `easy is better`. You do not give much clarity in your code by doing that (and depending on the IDE-highlighting strategy, make it even worse for others). Furthermore, the choice of your shortcut, namely `p`, is really a bad idea. How about people writing code with prime numbers (and `P` is not a good idea too).

For performances, there is no gain I think. Since `print` is a built-in function, you actually add a variable inside `globals()` or `locals()`. In my opinion, this is 1) not a good practice to use shortcuts like that 2) not an improvement in performance.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea if it is a good practice in python, but in general I would say no.

It will take away readability for other readers of your code. If the codebase grows large and you replace a lot of functions with very short names you make it difficult to read in general.

Coming from many years of code maintenance if I was called out in the middle of the night to fix a code problem in production and found code like that I am pretty sure I would hunt you down in the morning and ask why you would ever do such a thing.

If you are lazy and doesn't want to write so much - get your self an editor that can complete code for you instead.

Comment: yes you're right (I just wanted to know other guys opinion!). actually one of python's Zen is: "Readability counts." . thanks anyway!

Comment: Trust me - in the middle of the night - readability is everthing!! Especially if you are working with other peoples code. That said - your own code can be equally difficult to understand one or two years after you made it.